# VB.NET is seeing the wrong monitor as having the TaskBar for computing the height

Tags: vb.net, winforms, multiple-monitors, taskbar

When I run this VB.NET code in my WinForms program it displays the expected results if Monitor #1 is on the left, and Monitor #2 is on the right.
(And Monitor #1 contains the Windows TaskBar.)

But if the user has his monitors switched around, with Monitor #2 on the left (containing the TaskBar), and #1 on the right... the height is now wrong.
My code then (incorrectly) assumes the Monitor with the TaskBar has a LARGER value for the height.

Is there a way to fix that?  (Without forcing 1000s of users to switch their Monitors around... or switch the TaskBars to the other monitor.)

Or am I totally misunderstanding "WorkingArea()"????

```
Dim msg As String = ""

Dim numberOfMonitors As Int16 = Screen.AllScreens.GetUpperBound(0) + 1

If (numberOfMonitors >= 1) Then msg &= "Monitor #1 = " & Screen.AllScreens(0).WorkingArea.Width & " x " & Screen.AllScreens(0).WorkingArea().Height & ".    "
If (numberOfMonitors >= 2) Then msg &= "Monitor #2 = " & Screen.AllScreens(1).WorkingArea.Width & " x " & Screen.AllScreens(1).WorkingArea().Height & ".    "

Call MsgBox(msg)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you are not misunderstanding Working area.  Here is the definition from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.workingarea%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The working area is the desktop area of the display, excluding taskbars, docked windows, and docked tool bars.
>
> WorkingArea will return the entire area of the screen if the Windows Taskbar is set to Auto-Hide, no matter whether the Taskbar is currently displayed or not.

I would look into two propertys of the Screen class one is [`Primary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primary%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which returns a Boolean value indicating wether or not that screen is the Primary, the second is just use the [`PrimaryScreen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.screen.primaryscreen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Property to get the Working area of your Primary Screen.

*Caveat:  I do not have a dual monitor system powered up at this time to verify if this works.*